# Como criar campo dinamicamente com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma function que preciso validar o que o usuário digitou, se caso for `true` habilita o `datepicker`. Mas do jeito que fiz está caindo no método `POST` do `asp.net` `mvc`.
Existe uma maneira de criar um `textbox` dinamicamente com `jQuery` ?

Meu código:

View:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var senha = $('txtSenha').val();

    $("#lblSenha").hide();
    $('#txtNovaDtVenc').click(function () { <-- Aqui é o Datepicker
        $("#lblSenha").toggle();
        $('#btnOK').click(function () {
            if (senha == "administrador") {
                $("#txtNovaDtVenc").datepicker(
                    "option", "disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>

<div id="lblSenha" style="width:300px">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Senha: 
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("txtSenha", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:100px" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="btnOk" class="" value="Ok" onclick=""/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo simples, onde um `input` do tipo `text` é adicionado ao `body`

```
    $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'text',
        name: 'nome_do_campo',
        value: 'teste valor'
    }).appendTo('body');
```

Caso queira adicionar a um elemento específico, basta especificá-lo no método `appendTo()`.

```
<form id="frm"></form>

$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'nome_do_campo',
    value: 'teste valor'
}).appendTo('#frm');
```

Comment: Cara porque que quando eu clico no meu botão ok ele cai no método post do asp.net mvc ? não tem como eu fazer isso só em jQuery ?

Comment: Isso ocorre por que o seu botão é tipo submit, o comportamento padrão desse tipo de botão é justamente enviar os dados do form (POST ou GET). Se você quer mudar esse comportamento você trocar o tipo do botão para button por exemplo.

Comment: Provavemente porque é um botão do tipo "submit". Talvez seja melhor trocar para o tipo "button".

Comment: @DanielOmine Cara, deu certo trocar pra button, mas eu tenho outro e não tem id né ? E também, a hora que eu coloco no caso a senha certa, não habilita o datepicker.

Comment: aí já são outros 500..  procure resolver e se tiver dúvida abre nova pergunta espcífica sobre o datepicker..

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo pronto feito no jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kro8mud9/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var counter = 2;
  
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
    
 if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
 }   
  
 var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                
 newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>'     + '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
       '" id="idCampo' + counter + '" value="" >');
            
 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    
 counter++;
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
  <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1'>
 </div>
</div>
    
<input type='button' value='Add TextBox' id='addButton'>
```

Comment: Poste o código do JSfiddle aqui assim a resposta ficará eternizada independente de sites externos.

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação @Ricardo !